# JSON encoding a zero value embedded json.Marshaler panics, would you consider this a bug?

Tags: json, go, interface, marshalling

```
json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(struct {
    M json.Marshaler
}{})
```

panics:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not json.Marshaler
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Vur0JJq6SF

I'd like to explicitly state for my interface that it should marshal itself:

```
type thing interface {
    json.Marshaler
    Type() string
    ....
}
```

would you consider this a bug? If no, why not?

Comment: Interesting question, I see merit for both sides of the argument.